# How to apply these few css settings with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a navigation bar. When I scroll down, I want it to become thinner. I have the code working but I can't get the styles to apply.. The dev tools say they are being applied but they are not. So with jquery or just vanilla js, how can I apply these settings at once. Here is a screen shot of how it "should" work:

- [Before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsfEZ.png)
- [After scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80QBf.png)

for some reason I can't post the css here, so here [is a link to codepen](http://codepen.io/devuxx/pen/jBojjq).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // all custom jQuery will go here
    var nav = $(".main-nav");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > 5 ){
            nav.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
        }else{
            nav.removeClass("main-nav-scrolled");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2; }
  .fixed-nav li,
  .fixed-nav a {
    height: 110px;
    line-height: 110px; }

.fixed-nav {
  height: 50px; }
  .fixed-nav li,
  .fixed-nav a {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px; }

.menu {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.menu a {
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase; }
  .menu a:visited {
    color: #333; }
  .menu a:hover, .menu a:target {
    color: #ED1C24;
    transition: color 0.4s; }

.menu-items {
  display: inline-block; }

.sitename {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px; }

a.sitename, a:visited.sitename {
  color: #e0e0e0; }

.menu-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px; }
.menu-items a {
  text-decoration: none; }

.show, .hide {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  color: #dde1e2; }

.show {
  background-image: url(assets/down-arrow-icon.png); }

.hide {
  background-image: url(assets/up-arrow-icon.png); }

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; }

  .sitename {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    margin-left: 0px; }

  .menu-items {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #fff; }
    .menu-items li {
      display: block;
      text-align: center; }

  .show, .hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px; }

  .show {
    display: inline-block; }

  .hide {
    display: none; }

  #menu:target .show {
    display: none; }
  #menu:target .hide, #menu:target .menu-items {
    display: inline-block; } }
@media only screen and (max-width: 220px) {
  .sitename, .show, .hide {
    font-size: 14px; } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns main-nav fixed-nav">
          <div class="menu" id="menu"><a class="sitename" href="#">Brand-Logo</a> <a class="show" href="#menu">Menu</a><a class="hide" href="#hidemenu">Menu</a>
            <ul class="menu-items">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Empty</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You don't have style `main-nav-scrolled` defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define properties for `.main-nav-scrolled` class first. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // all custom jQuery will go here
  var nav = $(".main-nav");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 5) {
      nav.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
    } else {
      nav.removeClass("main-nav-scrolled");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

.fixed-nav li,
.fixed-nav a {
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
}

.fixed-nav {
  height: 70px;
}

.fixed-nav li,
.fixed-nav a {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu a {
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a:visited {
  color: #333;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu a:target {
  color: #ED1C24;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

.menu-items {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sitename {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

a.sitename,
a:visited.sitename {
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

.menu-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.show,
.hide {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  color: #dde1e2;
}

.show {
  background-image: url(assets/down-arrow-icon.png);
}

.hide {
  background-image: url(assets/up-arrow-icon.png);
}

.main-nav-scrolled {
  height: 45px;
}

.main-nav-scrolled .menu-items {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns main-nav fixed-nav">
          <div class="menu" id="menu"><a class="sitename" href="#">Brand-Logo</a> <a class="show" href="#menu">Menu</a><a class="hide" href="#hidemenu">Menu</a>
            <ul class="menu-items">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes
here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff
Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br>SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes
here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br> SomeStuff Goes here<br>
```

Comment: yeah I know I need to define the properties for .fixed-nav. The problem is that I have to also apply them for the li and a elements under it. If i do that the same as the .fixed-nav, it doesnt work. But if I hard code them to the settings, it does. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @JoshBeyer ofcourse you have to apply for `li` and `a` elements... see the snippet, i have used `.main-nav-scrlloed` as well as `.main-nav-scrlloed .menu-items`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's .scrollTop() method. Basically, you have two css files that will get applied depending on whether the user scrolls to a certain position or not. Here's an example:

```
$(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                $(".header").addClass("smaller");
            } else {
                $(".header").removeClass("smaller");
            }
        });
    });
```

That code above will add the smaller class to the header class whenever the user scroll is greater than or equal to 100 pixels, otherwise it will be removed. Then you can just change the height or hide some objects whenever smaller class is applied. You just need to know basic css for that.